# Tkinter button unsuable after first use

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for question, new to PY.  I am trying to create a random generator which would select from the list and print the result. I was able to get this done with the following code

```
import random

exercises = ['Bodyweight Squat 4x8','Step Back Lunge 4x8', 'Push Ups 4x10',
            '2 Min Kettle Bell Swing', 'Kettle Bell Sit-ups 4x5', '1 Min Plank',
            'Pistol Squat 4x10', '1 Min Flutter Kicks', 'Crunches 4x10', 'Dips 4x5',
            'Goblet Squat 4x5', 'Turkish Get-Up 4x5', 'Kettle Bell Press 5x10',
            'Kettle Bell Clean 4x10']
while True:
    x=random.choice(exercises)
    input("<Press Enter>")
    print(x)
```

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title('Random Workout Generator')
root.geometry('400x300')
topFrame= Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame= Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
label2=Label(root,text='Click the button, fatty',font=('arial',10))
label2.pack(side=TOP,pady=10)
#window size and title

def click():

# 14 exercises
        exercises = ['Bodyweight Squat 4x8','Step Back Lunge 4x8', 'Push Ups 4x10',
            '2 Min Kettle Bell Swing', 'Kettle Bell Sit-ups 4x5', '1 Min Plank',
            'Pistol Squat 4x10', '1 Min Flutter Kicks', 'Crunches 4x10', 'Dips 4x5',
            'Goblet Squat 4x5', 'Turkish Get-Up 4x5', 'Kettle Bell Press 5x10',
            'Kettle Bell Clean 4x10']
    #convert to set
        exercises_set= set(exercises)
    #convert back to list
        unique_exercises= list(exercises_set)
    #create list size variable
        total_number = len(unique_exercises) - 1
    #random number between 0 & 14
        rando = randint(0, total_number)

        winnerLabel = Label(root, text=unique_exercises[rando], font=('arial', 20,"bold"))
        winnerLabel.pack(pady=50)

Button1 = Button(topFrame, text= 'Generate', fg='purple',font=('helvetica', 15),command= click)
Button1.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

however, after the first click on the button it becomes unusable. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first click, it **is** still usable, the text **is** displays it's just hidden (try maximizing the window).

One way to fix this is to create the label outside the `click()` function, and in `click()` just **edit** the text of the label with `.config()`. This way there is only one label being edited each time.

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title('Random Workout Generator')
root.geometry('400x300')
topFrame= Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame= Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
label2=Label(root,text='Click the button, fatty',font=('arial',10))
label2.pack(side=TOP,pady=10)
#window size and title

def click():

# 14 exercises
        exercises = ['Bodyweight Squat 4x8','Step Back Lunge 4x8', 'Push Ups 4x10',
            '2 Min Kettle Bell Swing', 'Kettle Bell Sit-ups 4x5', '1 Min Plank',
            'Pistol Squat 4x10', '1 Min Flutter Kicks', 'Crunches 4x10', 'Dips 4x5',
            'Goblet Squat 4x5', 'Turkish Get-Up 4x5', 'Kettle Bell Press 5x10',
            'Kettle Bell Clean 4x10']
    #convert to set
        exercises_set= set(exercises)
    #convert back to list
        unique_exercises= list(exercises_set)
    #create list size variable
        total_number = len(unique_exercises) - 1
    #random number between 0 & 14
        rando = randint(0, total_number)

        winnerLabel.config(text=unique_exercises[rando])

winnerLabel = Label(root, font=('arial', 20,"bold"))
winnerLabel.pack(pady=50)


Button1 = Button(topFrame, text= 'Generate', fg='purple',font=('helvetica', 15),command= click)
Button1.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code where I have just replaced that pack manager with the following statement -

```
winnerLabel.place(x= 0, y = 150, height = 100, width = 400)
```

The problem was with the pack manager. I recommend using the place manager. Replace the packing of the winnerLabel in the function with the above placing code.

---

Here is the complete code -

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title('Random Workout Generator')
root.geometry('400x300')
topFrame= Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame= Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
label2=Label(root,text='Click the button, fatty',font=('arial',10))
label2.pack(side=TOP,pady=10)
count = [0,0]
#window size and title

def click():
# 14 exercises
        exercises = ['Bodyweight Squat 4x8','Step Back Lunge 4x8', 'Push       Ups 4x10','2 Min Kettle Bell Swing', 'Kettle Bell Sit-ups 4x5', '1 Min Plank',
        'Pistol Squat 4x10', '1 Min Flutter Kicks', 'Crunches 4x10', 'Dips 4x5',
        'Goblet Squat 4x5', 'Turkish Get-Up 4x5', 'Kettle Bell Press 5x10',
        'Kettle Bell Clean 4x10']
#convert to set
    exercises_set= set(exercises)
#convert back to list
    unique_exercises= list(exercises_set)
#create list size variable
    total_number = len(unique_exercises) - 1
#random number between 0 & 14
    rando = randint(0, total_number)



    winnerLabel = Label(root, text=unique_exercises[rando], font=('arial', 20,"bold"))
    winnerLabel.place(x= 0, y = 150, height = 100, width = 400)
    count.append(1)
```

Button1 = Button(topFrame, text= 'Generate', fg='purple',font=('helvetica', 15),command= click)
Button1.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=20)

root.mainloop()

Comment: But, it works if you don't maximize the window. Only, its position is changed when you maximize.